# JSOUP - doc cannot be resolved and doc cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm attempting to implement a JSOUP query however I'm getting an error stating "doc cannot be resolved" and "doc cannot be resolved to a variable" I know I'll need to call doc before I can use it I'm just not sure how to do so yet - It's my first time building a parser with JSOUP - I'm sure it's pretty simple - I just need a quick pointer.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    TextView tv;
    String url = "http://microsoft.com";
String tr;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        new MyTask().execute(url);
    }

    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog prog;
        String title = "";

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prog.setMessage("Loading....");
            prog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableElement = doc.select(".datagrid").first();

                    Elements tableRows = tableElement.select("tr");
                    for (Element row : tableRows) {
                        Elements cells = row.select("td");
                        if (cells.size() >0) {
                            System.out.println(cells.get(0).text()+"; "+cells.get(1).text()+"; "+cells.get(2).text()+"; "+cells.get(3).text());
                        }
                    }}   catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return title;
        }




        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            prog.dismiss();
            tv.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never create the object doc, that's why. Either you create it as a field before and initialize in the method, or create it as a local variable. The later would probably be best suited for you unless you intend to use it outside the method.

Comment: I do plan on using it outside this method... How might I instantiate it as a field? (if you'd like you can post your response as an answer and I'll accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a variable that has not been declared. Just as you have done with

```
TextView tv;
```

you will have to declare the variable doc.

```
Document doc;
```

Don't forget to import the following package `org.jsoup.nodes.Document`.